# Installing psycopg2 in virtualenv (Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.5)

Tags: python, virtualenv, psycopg2

I had problems installing psycopg2 in a virtualenv.

I tried different things explained there: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/07/using-psycopg2-virtualenv-ubuntu-jaunty/

The last thing I tried is this...
I created a virtualenv with `-p python2.5 --no-site-packages`
I installed libpq-dev: `apt-get install libpq-dev`

In the virtualenv, I did this: `easy_install -i http://downloads.egenix.com/python/index/ucs4/ egenix-mx-base`

Then when I tried `pip install psycopg2==2.0.7`, I got this error:

```
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Running setup.py install for psycopg2
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.2.2 (dt dec ext pq3)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080404 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DHAVE_PQPROTOCOL3=1 -I/usr/include/python2.5 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.5/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:31:
./psycopg/python.h:31:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
./psycopg/python.h:34:4: error: #error "psycopg requires Python >= 2.4"
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From python-list:

> *Diez:*
>   Install the python-dev-package. It
>   contains the Python.h file, which the
>   above error message pretty clearly
>   says. Usually, it's a good idea to
>   search package descriptions of
>   debian/ubuntu packages for missing
>   header files to know what to install.
>
> > *Pascal:*
> >     It's already installed; at least for
> >     Python 2.6, nor sure it's correct for
> >     Python 2.5. python2.5-dev is not available but
> >     python-old-doctools seems to replace it.
> >
> > > *Diez:*
> > >       It is 100% *not* correct for
> > >       python2.5. As the error message shows
> > >       - it's missing.
> > >       If it's not available somewhere, you
> > >       should consider building python
> > >       yourself, if you have to use 2.5.
> > >
> > > *Alex:*
> > >       Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't have a full
> > >       Python 2.5 packaged, as evidenced by
> > >       the lack of python2.5-dev. You need to
> > >       use Python 2.6 or if you absolutely
> > >       must use Python 2.5 build it from
> > >       source, try a Debian package or switch
> > >       distro. python-old-doctools does not
> > >       replace python- dev, it looks like it
> > >       was bodged to keep some latex tools
> > >       working.
> > >
> > > > *Pascal:* I finally created a virtualenv
> > > >         with Python 2.6 and everything went fine
> > > >         (with the latest version of psycopg2).