# Virtualenv: psycopg2 and mxDateTime

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [easy_install libmysqld-dev error :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178535/easy-install-libmysqld-dev-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-clone)

Could anybody explain how I can install psycopg2 when using a virtualenv. Before I was using Ubuntu 11.04 I did the following and this work.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2 
pip install psycopg2
easy_install -i http://downloads.egenix.com/python/index/ucs4/ egenix-mx-base
```

On my new Ubuntu installation this doesn't seem to work anymore I get the following error:

```
Searching for egenix-mx-base
Reading http://downloads.egenix.com/python/index/ucs4/egenix-mx-base/
Reading http://downloads.egenix.com/python/index/ucs4/egenix-mx-base/3.1.3
No local packages or download links found for egenix-mx-base
Best match: None
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

What I want to do in the end is use postgresql with Django so if there are other ways that are less complex feel free to share those as well.

**Edit:**

Since this got closed I'll be naughty and post the a solution inside the question:

To fix this in Ubuntu 11.04 make sure you are inside your virtualenv.

```
wget http://downloads.egenix.com/python/egenix-mx-base-3.2.0_dev_20100819.linux-x86_64-py2.7_ucs4.prebuilt.zip
unzip, cd, python setup.py install
```

So download the zip, unzip it, cd into the directory you unzipped and run the setup.py file with install. This will manually install the egenix-mx-base which you need for the mxDateTime module.

Hope this helps others cause I had a real hard time finding some decent information on how to fix this.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one linked above. In fact, the linked "duplicate" only overlaps with this question in-so-far as they are both django and python. This question specifically deals with using virtualenv, postgresql, psycopg2, and the well-known-but-hard-to-reconcile psycopg2 dependency on mx.DateTime. [This question is the actual duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847536/installing-psycopg2-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-10-04-python-2-5)